# Using Dataframe calls with integer like column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly-dash

I'm trying to extract some information from my data set. Column names are City, TOTAL, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021

I can use dfc.City and dfc.TOTAL and they work perfectly fine.
How can I call 2018 and rest like this?

dfc['2018'] doesn't seem to work for me :/

This code is in @app.callback for plotly dash. Weird enough dfc.City,dfc.TOTAL, dfc['2018'] works outside the callback.

Is there any fix or workaround for this?

Thank you

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(dfc.columns[1:]),
                fill_color='paleturquoise',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[dfc.City,dfc.TOTAL ],
               fill_color='lavender',
               align='left'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the column is an integer you don't need quotes- in this case just use dfc[2018] (no quotes).

Comment: Well it didnt work. I can't call it with brackets but it works with "dot". 
I think there is a small trick like we use "r" in path. I'm trying to use dfc.2018